# Advisor says I shouldn't expect to finish thesis soon, but won't offer specific feedback on what is missing; how to react?

Tags: thesis, advisor

I have a rough draft of my PhD dissertation, on which I was working on and off for about a year, but mostly I was doing other coursework. I have about 90 pages so far.

My dissertation advisor tells me that what I should do is pretty much make sure it is well-written and apply the theory to a few examples. By my estimates, if I go berserk on this, I can finish all that in under one month.

However, the dissertation advisor says that usually, it takes about 3 years to complete a dissertation in my department, and I should not expect to complete it soon. Also, he says that the level of my draft was intermediate (some time ago) and not yet advanced (but he hasn't reviewed the current one yet).

When I ask or suggest about expanding the scope of the dissertation / adding additional chapters, the dissertation advisor says he does not think it is necessary.

So, it appears that the dissertation is almost complete, but I should not expect to complete it soon. How should I interpret this apparent contradiction?

Comment: What field are we talking about?

Comment: The field is physics.

Comment: How long have you been working on your dissertation and did it lead to any publication? Also, depending on your subfield, “applying your theory to some examples” is the major, time-consuming challenge.

Comment: I started working on it last year, but most of the time I was doing a large number of courses, so the effective time would be more like 5 months, which is of course not much. I wrote a technical report and an article during this time. The article is yet to be reviewed by the advisor.

Comment: I looked at previous dissertations completed in my department, and in similar cases, application of the theory to some examples is something like 20 pages and can be a relatively trivial task. This is further confirmed by the advisor's suggestions.

Comment: How many pages it is when written up does not necessarily correspond to how much work it was to get it all done right. Having the basic idea and theory may be easy and one is tempted to say "Here's the theory, the rest is trivial", but often only when you try to apply it, you will see the flaws and issues it has. Getting that fixed can be really time-consuming...

Comment: _if I go berserk on this, I can finish all that in under one month._ — So three years sound about right, then. (Ha ha only serious.)

Comment: So, you actually want to do a PHD without not even a peer-reviewed publication? In Physics? Not possible. First publish. More than once. Then write dissertation. Then get a PHD. A PHD is not a MSc, where you pass some courses, write a thesis that just makes your advisor and your committee happy (without the prerequisite of a peer-reviewed publication) and instant PHD in less than two years.

Comment: To all those focusing on publishing: in some fields (e.g. math) people have gotten tenure-track or tenured positions without publishing a paper.  It's extremely rare, and maybe it couldn't happen in the current state of affairs.  But there is precedent, so I wouldn't say "impossible".  Just very unlikely.

Comment: @JeffE Indeed, for various reasons, students often take more time than necessary to complete their thesis, and what you said makes sense.

Comment: @Alexandros Actually, I would prefer to have a peer-reviewed publication before graduating, but my advisor does not want me to worry about that. However, there is a possibility of publishing the paper I have completed, as well as papers based on material in my thesis draft. In my department, the expectation is about one paper per year if not enough progress is being made on the thesis, or something like that.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Indeed, it is very possible to get the PhD without publishing a single paper, although I would prefer to have some publications.

Comment: @Jake It is not really a matter of preference. Have you ever considered that your paper might get rejected? Or the peer-review process reveals some subtle mistake you have missed and ruins your results? Then your thesis will document what? Your possibly faulty results?

Comment: _Indeed, for various reasons, students often take more time than necessary_ — Actually my point was exactly the opposite: For various reasons, students often want to take less time than necessary.

Comment: @JeffE: There's a rule I once heard: "To determine how long a task will actually take: make your best estimate, double it, and switch to the next higher unit of time."  So "two hours" becomes "four days", and "one month" becomes "two years".  It should be Somebody's Law but I don't know whose.  ([Hofstadter's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law) is closely related.)

Comment: @Alexandros I have considered that. In fact, I knew that my previous version of the paper I have just submitted to the advisor would not be published; right now it is likely to be publishable after major revisions. However, I am sure that there are no substantial errors in my research, as the concept is sound, straightforward, and already tested. There are many small items to be taken care of, and that is what my advisor refers to, saying that I should have a well-written version of what I have already done.

Comment: @JeffE I think that both statements are true in different ways. Students often underestimate the time required to complete work, but they often work with very low efficiency, and especially so if they have unclear understanding of the dissertation process.

Comment: @NateEldredge In the formulations of this that I have encountered, the actual time to completion is about twice the estimated time. However, one day effectively consists of about 8 hours, according to a popular convention based on practice, so it is easy to see how a 2 hour task can be stretched out over several days.

Comment: In my department we require 4 publications to get a PhD. When I started, the head of studies said that even if I get there very much ahead of time, he would not let me graduate too soon, as an important part of PhD studies are just being in a scientific environment. One year is definitely not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My PhD advisor once told me that one aspect he considers when rating a thesis is how much the candidate did try to go beyond the initial idea or goal. If they are like "I solved the initial problem, here's the thesis, I just want to finish a fast as possible" then they will earn an intermediate grade at the end. Only if they try to go beyond the initial problem, try to at least estimate the further implications or steps or apply the outcome of the initial problem to further problems, they really can earn a top grade.

To my experience, to successfully finish a physics PhD within roughly a year, you have to have had really great luck to find something really excitingly new that provided a huge progress to your specific field. In most cases after one year you can't even tell for sure what the final focus of the thesis will be. Those applications of the theory to some example cases can easily take up more time than the whole development of the theory as there might come up issues and flaws that you were not expecting. Also their importance is not necessarily reflected in the number of pages they make up in the final thesis.

Therefore it seems to me, that you are somewhat belonging to the first type of people mentioned above who are just heading to leave before really having understood the implications of what they were working on.

Comment: The topic I am working on is considered to be quite "hot", and the theory I have developed is substantially new. It would be directly applicable to some high-profile research currently in progress at certain major laboratories.

Comment: The objective I have in mind for the dissertation is to complete it as quickly as possible, because I have lots of plans and ideas I can't wait to start working on after that, but I will take as long as it takes in order to not compromise on quality and scope.

Comment: @user162562 Then contacting some people there and asking for a collaboration to get your theory applied to their stuff should be an easy thing. If the theory is that good and new they should be glad to set up a collaboration and some high-profile publications should result from it. This is finally what academic work is about.

Comment: "Those applications of the theory to some example cases can easily take up more time than the whole development of the theory as there might come up issues and flaws that you were not expecting." -- I agree; however, I've already done testing on a few examples, and everything appears to work as it should so far. Also, the advisor is actually recommending me to focus on simply having a well-written version of part of the theory and not to extend the scope + the application to examples, of course.

Comment: "Then contacting some people there and asking for a collaboration to get your theory applied to their stuff should be an easy thing."
Thanks for the answer and for this suggestion. I think that it is a good idea, and I will work on that.

Comment: PhDs are pass/fail so I'm not sure what you mean for a thesis to "earn an intermediate grade".

Comment: What you describe sound like a **paper**, not a **thesis**. By all means, finish your current work, publish it, and move on. But that's independent from finishing your thesis.  (Warning: I work in a different field with different cultural expectations.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That depends, here in Germany they are graded and the first sentences don't just refer to PhDs but also bachelor's and master's theses.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, in my case the thesis is assigned a pass/failed grade.

Comment: @JeffE I am doing exactly what was agreed upon with the advisor for the thesis. On average, in my department dissertations are about 150 pages long (doublespaced), 20 of which is implicit content. Papers, on the other hand, are usually 3-15 pages long, sometimes up to about 30.  I am speaking of my field, of course. Right now, both in terms of content and length, the draft is more than a paper, but less than a thesis.

Comment: @Jake You seem to be viewing a PhD thesis as being merely a document that meets some specific set of criteria. It isn't. I think you should have a discussion with your adviser about what exactly a PhD is and what is expected of a thesis.

Comment: @Jake To build on David's comment, you also seem to be viewing a *paper* as being merely a document that meets some specific set of criteria.  It isn't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's one of the possible ways to look at it, as form is often correlated to its content. I did discuss this with my advisor, and I read some literature on PhD and dissertations.

Comment: @JeffE Quite apparently, a paper is a piece of scientific content, which satisfies conventional requirements for its form. There is often a correlation between content and form, which is why one may speak of content as well as of form. It is often  convenient to briefly mention form and management parameters, content being idiosyncratic and specialized.

Answer (score 5):

Science is really a publication driven field, not a dissertation driven one. I would *highly* encourage to you to put your time in to turning your research into peer-reviewed scientific publication, instead of doing just enough for a dissertation. If you can publish 2-4 papers out of what you have written in established journals your adviser will most likely graduate you. However, I imagine, since this was my experience too, that as you start to write your papers you will find holes that need to be fixed, etc., and fixing those holes will be a substantial part of the work.

Bottom line: focus on doing publishable research and getting published first! After you've done that, the dissertation will be easy and you'll graduate without a problem.

Comment: I agree that it would be best to publish 2-4 papers. The subject matter in my case is pretty straightforward, but you are right about certain seemingly small items that may require substantial work. I have a list of such items, and on average, each of them takes about 1-3 days to be addressed. The advisor and I agree that the main concern is that my draft is not very well-written yet, and for the same reason, I don't have much publishable material at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get a PhD in a year or two is a bad idea, because employers will not take such a degree seriously. The only exception is if you're a once-in-a-generation talent (and the odds are you're not the next Albert Einstein or Lev Landau), in which case you'd already have a number of publications to your credit and enough work to justify a PhD.

So I would echo Benedikt Bauer's advice and not try to rush through things. Instead, focus on the **quality** of your thesis project. Have you completed publications? Have you personally explored the ramifications of the work you've already done? What else have you done "beyond the basics" of the original problem?

Comment: "Have you completed publications?"
I wrote a technical report and an article during this time. The article is yet to be reviewed by the advisor.

Comment: "Have you personally explored the ramifications of the work you've already done?"
Yes, I have done that, but the only thing I head from the advisor on that is that he thinks I should not over-do things like that.

Comment: "What else have you done "beyond the basics" of the original problem?"
The advisor wants me to have a well-written version of what I've done, plus application of theory to a few examples, which is pretty much feeding certain data to the method and analyzing the output; this should take about 20 pages, and I can imagine in detail how it will look. There are a lot of ideas that I mentioned, but the advisor does not want me to explore too many of them.

Comment: "Trying to get a PhD in a year or two is a bad idea, because employers will not take such a degree seriously." I suppose that maybe my advisor wants me to take time with the dissertations for reasons such as this one.

Comment: One paper in any event is not really sufficient for a PhD. Even for a three-year PhD, one would normally require output corresponding to multiple journal papers (or the equivalent in your field). For instance, I expect my students to have completed work roughly equivalent to three papers.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Basically that's true, but getting a PhD is also not a drive-by task. And the attitude that shines through the OP is something like "I was attending some courses the last year and the time remaining beside the course work I wrote a bit on my thesis." It's unquestioned that some famous people may have achieved their successful work in a similar way (as aeismail noted already), but it's quite unlikely that this happened to the OP as well. Also if the OP was one of those talents, I guess their supervisor would show some more enthusiasm about their work.

Comment: @aeismail I heard that in some countries like Finland, publishing three papers is considered to be equivalent to completing a thesis. I agree with you on the advisable number of publications. Right now, the content of my draft is roughly equivalent to one "average" paper and one "very good" paper, with lots of extra material that is not yet detailed enough to be equivalent to any number of papers. By the time I complete in its present scope at the expected quality level, it will be indeed roughly equivalent to 3-4, maybe 5 papers.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I agree.

Comment: @BenediktBauer In my opinion, I am not one of those once-in-a-generation talents, but I am quite unique and unusual (not necessarily in an exclusively positive way; more like in a mixed way with a lot of positive), which was noted by my advisor and other people. My question is mostly motivated by search of clarity, and I objectively noted that at the moment, I have so far committed relatively little time to the thesis.

Comment: I think that I can perhaps technically complete the thesis within a few months of normal-paced work, and the advisor understands that, but spending an additional year or two would guarantee a substantial improvement in its quality, and perhaps that's what the advisor wants me to do.

Answer (score 1):

In all the programs I am familiar with, **you become a "doctoral candidate" (or something similar) only after having successfully proposed a topic for your dissertation**.  Usually that proposal includes several pages of detail regarding **what will be accepted by your committee as successful completion**.  Of course, research is uncertain and there must be some flexibility, but your proposal can be viewed as the basis for deciding when you are done.

If you have such a document, you should reference it specifically in discussions with your advisor.  If you do not, perhaps you should create one and iterate with your advisor until he/she is willing to agree to it.

Comment: The confusing thing is that what remains to be done is simply brushing up the existing draft, perhaps even deleting some extra material, and adding application of theory to some examples, the latter being already done to a small extent for proof of concept purposes. So it would appear that although I have recently started, I am almost done, but at the same time, the expected timeframe remains about 3 years in total. Perhaps I can practically complete the thesis in a few months and spend an additional year simply improving its "awesomeness" factor.

Comment: Do you have a proposal document that defines what remains to be done?  If not, your perception and your advisor's may be vastly different.

Comment: A formal thesis proposal is not required in my department, but I have discussed this in maximal possible detail with the advisor, which is limited by his time availability and willingness to discuss those details. In the latest discussions, it was apparent that his expectations for scope are somewhat smaller than mine. I can easily satisfy all of the requirements he mentioned perhaps even all too quickly, and he does not think I should be concerned about anything else.

Comment: All I can think of is that he wants me to do a lot of additional unspecified work on the thesis, which would be pretty much reworking every detail to a higher quality, and that I should take time doing it, and not merely complete the dissertation plan with sufficient quality.